# Can't change select form option when on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a select form that has a list of currencies as options when my screen is at full size the select input works fine but the second I resize it to anything smalller I can only change my select option once. After that the clicks will not register and the mouse will not focus on the select unless I go back to a full sized screen. I also can't seem to reproduce the problem, I am using angular js

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <select required="required" ng-model="currency" name="type" default-option="Select Currency" class="form-control m-b">
    <option>Yuan</option>
    <option>JPY</option>
    <option>USD</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Where have you picked those CSS classes?
Try using `%` instead of `px`. Maybe that can help.

Comment: removed classes, didn't help.